# Added custom button in edit form while using 4 jqgrids in one page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have created custom button on edit form  on beforeShowForm jqgrid. i am using 4 jqgrids in one page, but from below code Button has been Created to all the grids Edit form, and on click of each button everytime its calling the same function, i have 2 question.

1. How to add different button for different Edit form of grid.
2. How do i differentiate button click of each Jqgrid edit form.

here is my code

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
            recreateForm: true,
            beforeShowForm: function () {                    
                var $self = $(this);
                $('<a href="#">New Assignment<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>')
                    .click(function () {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:  '/DataHandler.ashx?MethodName=EditScreens',                               
                            dataType: "json"                             

                    });

                    }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
                      .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");
            },
```

Comment: where are you defining the `contentType` I would expect to see something like `contentType: 'application/json;',` for example

Comment: i have removed contentType , because somewhere i have seen that if you remove contentType , it will work fine.